# Como mudar a URL da página inicial do Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Olá, pessoas. Bom, tentarei ser o mais breve possível. Atualmente eu uso essa URL na minha página inicial:

`https://site.com/` que é o meu domínio

e gostaria que ela passasse a ser assim:

`https://site.com/br/` que seria o meu domínio com o **/br/**

Como eu posso fazer isso? Pra que fique claro, eu quero apenas que a minha **página inicial** mude, as outras páginas devem entrar normalmente sem a utilização do **/br/**, exemplo: `https://site.com/produtos/abacate/`

Answer (score -2):

Você pode construir a página /br no WP, mas não vincular as demais páginas à ela. Já na página principal, cria normal (pois vai precisar dela para criar as páginas de produto), mas na raiz / coloca um redirect para o /br. 
Caso a sua ideia seja ter uma/ e uma /br, aí é só colocar numa questão de botão, dependendo do template que estiver usando, ele já até deve ter uma função parecida.

Answer (score -2):

O site terá que ter uma página inicial, mesmo que não esteja sendo utilizada. Se for este o caso você pode criar uma nova página, ir em configurações > Leitura e escolher a nova página como a página inicial.

Depois disso, volte a página home e mude o link permanente para: `https://site.com/br/` (br passará a ser a nova url desta página).

Para a página inicial não ficar em branco ou desconfigurada, você poderá fazer um redirecionamento para esta nova página /br. Para isso você pode utilizar um plugin como o [redirection](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/), ou fazer um redirecionamento diretamente em seu arquivo .htaccess

Esperto ter ajudado, boa sorte!